# SSIS Date Expression for previous month

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, ssis, expression

I am trying to get the previous month from the expression i wrote but i am not having any luck. I want to be able to -1, -2 etc.. in my expression for last month. Help would be greatly appreciated.

`MONTH(Created) == MONTH(GETDATE()) && YEAR(Created) == YEAR(GETDATE())`

Comment: please show your expected output !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, the expression month() in SSIS returns DT_I4 - in other words ordinary int. You should be able to substract 1 from it.

So...

- `MONTH(Created)` should return `int` value which represents month number of the datetime-like column `Created` in the database
- `MONTH(GETDATE())` should return current month
- `MONTH(GETDATE()) - 1` should return previous month; however you should pay attention to the end-of-the-year wrapping, as the previous month in that case would be 0 and if you use that expression you should correct the number to 12
- everything is the same for year, except you don't have to pay attention to the wrapping

So, the expression you should use would be *something* like...

```
MONTH(Created) == CASE WHEN MONTH(GETDATE()) = 1 THEN 12 ELSE MONTH(GETDATE()) - 1 END
&& YEAR(Created) == YEAR(GETDATE())
```